Were emails real about my bitcoin?
I was receiving emails asking me to cash out or lose my bitcoin. I would receive them from different emails and for different amounts so I assumed they were spam. Not being updated on it at time I'm thinking they were trying to buy my bitcoin. Emails have been erased years ago. I don't even remember how I bought them. Are they just gone how could I find them? Help please I'm not computer smart or any technical expert at all.Thank you
Dawn Holder

Tempting offers in unexpected unsolicited email messages are a favourite tool of criminal confidence tricksters intending to deceive you into giving money to criminals.

Emails that exhibit some combination of the following signs
indicate that someone is trying to phish or scam you.
Red flags:

sent from suspicious domain names
communicate a sense of urgency
use a generic greeting
tell you about some unexpected windfalls
make unrealistic offers (e.g. "receive ₿10, if you send a $20 processing fee")
…

If you don’t remember buying Bitcoin or entering a cloud mining contract, it should make you suspicious when "Karen from Alpha Mega Trading" contacts you to remind you that you have a life-changing balance with them that you should collect.
